# How to delete facebook timeline photos with php graph api?

Tags: php, facebook

I like write one code, which this run time program, delete the last timeline photos, and i like graph api.

This my code:

```
             $facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $appid, 
'secret'  => $appSecret, 
'cookie' => true
 ));

 $acces_token=$facebook->getAccessToken();

 $facebook->api("/page_id/photos?access_token=".$acces_token,"DELETE");
```

Does not work!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a tag for a particular user in the photo by issuing a HTTP DELETE request to /PHOTO_ID/tags/USER_ID or PHOTO_ID/tags?to=USER_ID.

Deleting a tag on a photo requires the publish_stream permission and supports the following parameters.
Parameter   Description     Type    Required
to  USER_ID of the User to tag; can also be provided in URL path (see above).   string  yes

If the deletion is successful, you get the following return.
Description     Type
If the deletion succeeded   boolean

for more info study the graph api for photo     here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/